# Slidable container flutter with rounded corners

Tags: flutter

What i am trying to do:

[image]

I am trying to do this container to slide. The slide to start as the other items with the same margin and basically to have the background full another color and to keep the rounded corners of the item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to slide the button and in background of Text container more things to perform actions like delete,undo. You have to wrap that widget with *Dismissible*. Yoy can visit this site for docs https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/gestures/dismissible

Also there is a example code:

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

// MyApp is a StatefulWidget. This allows updating the state of the
// widget when an item is removed.
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final items = List<String>.generate(20, (i) => 'Item ${i + 1}');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Dismissing Items';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final item = items[index];
            return Dismissible(
              // Each Dismissible must contain a Key. Keys allow Flutter to
              // uniquely identify widgets.
              key: Key(item),
              // Provide a function that tells the app
              // what to do after an item has been swiped away.
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                // Remove the item from the data source.
                setState(() {
                  items.removeAt(index);
                });

                // Then show a snackbar.
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('$item dismissed')));
              },
              // Show a red background as the item is swiped away.
              background: Container(color: Colors.red),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(item),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````